# Jquery keyup event is not triggered outside of document ready function

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyup

I wrote the keyup event in an external js file and it's referenced in the html file.

```
$('input[name=restaurant]').keyup(function(event){
    console.log("keyup");
});
```

The strange thing is that it won't activate unless I include it in document ready function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name=restaurant]').keyup(function(event){
        console.log("keyup");
    });
});
```

The keyup event worked just fine outside of document ready function before.
I don't know what the problem is now.

Answer (score 1):

Because at the time your script ran, the element wasn't in the DOM yet. Thus, `$('input[name=restaurant]')` doesn't select any element, and no event listener is attached.

`$(document).ready()` waits for every element in the DOM to finish loading, then executes the callback.

See: [Document: DOMContentLoaded event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event)

Comment: Thank you now I have a clear understanding.